# property 'apps' is not included in return value from 'firebase-admin'

Tags: node.js, typescript, firebase, firebase-admin

I'm trying to decide whether of not calling initializeApp() is needed based on the property 'apps' returning from 'firebase-admin'. On the first try it worked as expected, but afterwards this error began to arise no matter how many times I tried.

Error:

> uncaughtException FirebaseAppError: The default Firebase app already
> exists. This means you called initializeApp() more than once without
> providing an app name as the second argument. In most cases you only
> need to call initializeApp() once. But if you do want to initialize
> multiple apps, pass a second argument to initializeApp() to give each
> app a unique name.

Code:

```
import * as firebase from 'firebase-admin';
console.log(firebase); // add this on second try
if (!firebase.apps.length) {
  firebase.initializeApp({
      credential: firebase.credential.cert(some config here),
      databaseURL: 'some url here',
  });
}
```

when I see the console, output is like:

```
FirebaseNamespace {
  __esModule: true,
  credential: {
    cert: [Function],
    refreshToken: [Function],
    applicationDefault: [Function]
  },
  SDK_VERSION: '9.5.0',
  Promise: [Function: Promise],
  INTERNAL: FirebaseNamespaceInternals { firebase_: [Circular], apps_: {} },
  default: [Circular]
}
```

There's no such property as 'apps'. Does anyone knows why this property does not exist?

UPDATE:

I've solved this problem by myself. It was an easy mistake.

After inspecting codes, I found an another place where the exact same logic is written. This logic runs second times, so the second one is giving this error.